# Making a Siyum on a Yahrzeit - allowed?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, siyum, yahrtzeit

I see and hear of people making a Siyum on a Yahrzeit - and we have questions to that effect on the site.

I am wondering why this is permitted. The  [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 221:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.221.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) forbids eating at a Siyum on a Yahrzeit; though in 221:7 he permits it during the evening of the Yahrzeit.

His source is the [Shach in Yoreh De'ah 246:27](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.246.26?lang=bi&with=Siftei%20Kohen&lang2=en)

**Is there a difference between a person commemorating a Yahrzeit attending a Siyum and participating in one?**
I'm curious to know if anybody has sources about this.

---

#### Sources

<sup>From Sefaria, with translation when provided.</sup>

**[Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 221:6-7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.221.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)**

> בְּיוֹם שֶׁאֵין אוֹמְרִים בּוֹ תַחֲנוּן, אֵין מִתְעַנִין תַּעֲנִית יָארְצַייט. וְכֵן בְּיוֹם מִילָה, הָאָב וְהַסַּנְדָק וְהַמּוֹהֵל אֵין מִתְעַנִּין. וְכֵן בְּפִדְיוֹן הַבֵּן, הָאָב וְהַכֹּהֵן אֵין מִתְעַנִּין. וְכֵן הֶחָתָן בְּשִׁבְעַת יְמֵי הַמִּשְׁתֶּה, אֵינוֹ מִתְעַנֶּה. **אֲבָל בִּסְעוּדַת סִיּוּם, אָסוּר לֶאֱכוֹל בְּיוֹם הַיָארְצַייט** (ש"ך יו"ד סִימָן רמו סָעִיף קָטָן כז בשם תשובת מהרי"ל). וּבְיָמִים שֶׁאֵינוֹ מִתְעַנֶּה, עַל כָּל פָּנִים יַעֲסֹק בַּתּוֹרָה וּבְמִצְוֹת וּבִשְׁאָר מַעֲשִׂים טוֹבִים לְזַכּוֹת נִשְׁמַת אָבִיו וְאִמּוֹ.‏
>
> On days that Tachanun is not said fasting should not be observed on the Yahrzeit. Also, on the day of a circumcision, the father, the Sandek, and the Mohel should not observe the Yahrzeit fast. Also, on the day of redemption of the firstborn, the father and Kohein should not observe the Yahrzeit fast. Also, a bridegroom, during the wedding week, should not observe a Yahrzeit fast. But **it is forbidden to partake of a meal at a Siyum on the day of a Yahrzeit**. On the days when fasting is not observed, he should at least devote his time to study Torah and to practice Mitzvos and good deeds to bring merit to the souls of his father and mother.
>
> בַּלַּיְלָה אֲשֶׁר בְּיוֹם הַמָּחֳרָת יִהְיֶה לוֹ יָארְצַייט, אֵין לוֹ לֶאֱכוֹל בִּסְעוּדַת חַתֻנָּה שֶׁיֶשׁ שָׁם מִזְמוּטֵי חָתָן וְכַלָּה וְיֶשׁ בָּהּ שִׂמְחָה. אֲבָל בִּסְעוּדַת בְּרִית מִילָה וּפִדְיוֹן הַבֵּן וְסִיּוּם מַסֶּכֶת, מֻתָּר.‏
>
> In the night preceding the day when one must observe Yahrzeit, he should not partake of a wedding meal, for there is music for the groom and bride and there is merriment. But to partake of a meal in honor of a circumcision, or the redemption of the firstborn or siyum is permitted.
>   <sup>(Mekom Shmuel Responsa 80. However, the Eliyohu Rabba 568:15 forbids attending the meal of a circumcision.)</sup>

**[ש"ך יו"ד סִימָן רמו סָעִיף קָטָן כז](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.246.26?lang=bi&with=Siftei%20Kohen&lang2=en)**

כשמסיים מסכתא כו'. וכתוב בסוף תשובת מהר"מ מינץ דכשבאין לסוף מסכתא ישייר מעט בסוף עד שעת הכושר יומא דראוי לתקן בו סעודה כו' ולכך נהגו כל הבעלי בתים לילך על הישיבה בתחלת הזמן ולכך מנהג להודיעם כשבא הרב לסיים המסכתא כדי שיבואו הב"ב גם כן לסיומא ואז יהיו שמה תחלה וסוף ויחזרו אחר מנין לומר קדיש דרבנן ועשרה בני רב פפא והיא סעודת מצוה דאפילו אבל תוך י"ב חודש על אביו ואמו יכול לסעוד שם כו' ועיין שם גם מהרש"ל כתב בפ' מרובה סי' ל"ז דסיום מסכתא סעודת מצוה היא ואסיק דמכל מקום אין לברך שהשמחה במעונו ובסוף הפרק כתב דאפי' מי שלא סיים מסכתא מצוה רבה שישמח עם המסיים ואפילו יחיד שסיים מחויבים אחרים לסיים עמו כו' עיין שם ובתשובות מהרי"ל סימן קע"ב **דביום שמת בו אביו או אמו דנהגו עלמא להתענות אסור לאכול בסיום מסכתא** דהוי כמו דברים המותרים ואחרים נהגו בו איסור (כדלעיל סימן רי"ד ועיין שם):‏

Comment: Are you assuming that the person making the siyum would otherwise be fasting?

Comment: @JoelK - Good point. I'm not assuming anything. I'm aware that nowadays fewer and fewer people fast on a Yahrzeit. (Not that I see anybody say that one can make a Siyum to break a Yahrzeit-fast.)

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is. If he is fasting he shouldn't eat and if he's not he can. What's the problem? The Kitzur just says that a siyum doesn't push off the fast (unlike a seudah at a bris for instance)

Comment: So you're both saying that those who make a Siyum have some heter not to fast. Is that correct? @DoubleAA

Comment: @Danny at least if they are eating at the siyum. I don't know if you can make a siyum while fasting and plan not to eat anything, but I suspect you can do so. Is that what you're wondering about?